# Linq to Entities filter navigation collection properties

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have an order class that has two navigation properties of type collections; OrderDetails and Categories.  There is a one to many relationship between Order and both OrderDetail and Category.  An Order may or may not have a Category associated to it.  An OrderDetail record has a CustomerID field.

I am trying to retrieve a list of Orders that have categories associated to them and their corresponding OrderDetail records for a specific customer.  I want to achieve this using linq to entities if possible.

```
public class order
{
    public order()
    {
        OrderDetails = new list<OrderDetail>();
        Categories = new list<Category>();
    }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Category> Categories{ get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetail
{
    public int OrderDetailID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

I can get it to work if I start with the OrderDetail entity first as shown below but how would I write this if I want to start with the Order entity first?

```
var query = from od in _dbCtx.OrderDetails
                .Include("Order")
                .Include("Order.Categories")
                where od.CustomerID == custID && od.Order.Categories.Count > 0
                select od;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var query =_dbCtx.Orders.Include("OrderDetails")
                        .Include("Categories")
                        .Where(o=>o.Categories.Count>0)
                        .SelectMany(o=>o.OrderDetails.Where(od=>od.CustomerID == custID));
```

The key in this query is the `SelectMany` extension method, which is used to flatten the  `Where`'s result  into one single collection.

### Edit 1

Due to you have disabled lazy loading, the `Order` navigation property in the OrderDetails that you get when you execute my query are `null`. One option could be using the `Load` method when you use the result:

```
foreach(var od in query)
{
   // Load the order related to a given OrderDetail
   context.Entry(od).Reference(p => p.Order).Load();

   // Load the Categories related to the order
   context.Entry(blog).Collection(p => p.Order.Categories).Load();
}
```

Another option could be returning an anonymous type:

```
var query =_dbCtx.Orders.Include("OrderDetails")
                        .Include("Categories")
                        .Where(o=>o.Categories.Count>0)
                        .SelectMany(o=>o.OrderDetails.Where(od=>od.CustomerID == custID).Select(od=>new {Order=o,OrderDetail=od}));
```

But I don't like anyone of these solutions.The most direct way is the query that you already had from the beginning.

Comment: I tried both and neither one gives me the result I want.  The first query is returning all the OrderDetails belonging to the Customer.  What I want to achieve is return the customer's OrderDetails for those Orders that have a category.  Sorry if I didn't clarify this in my original question.

Comment: I thought you want this:"_a list of Orders that have categories associated to them and their corresponding OrderDetail records for a specific customer_". Now reading the question again I saw you already have a solution, why do you need to start the query with `Orders`?

Comment: @filmon, I edited my answer, check now with that query

Comment: I tested with your new query and now I get just the OderDetails.  The corresponding Order and Categories are null.  You are right that I have it working if I start with the OrderDetails but I want to start with Orders b/c it makes logical sense in terms of the hierarchy.  Even if that wasn't the case, I am interested in getting it to work with Orders as I am learning EF and linq.

Comment: @filmon, I have edited my answer again. But, as I said above, you already had the best option

Comment: Thanks octavioccl; that gave me the right result but you are right I prefer the original solution I had so i will stick with that.

Comment: Order=o where 'o' does not exists, however its a good approach, i was able to get what i wanted.

Comment: The `o` is outside of the scope of the internal `Select` call, should be visible but also could be replaced by `od.Order` I guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

The default setting for Entity Framework is to allow lazy loading and dynamic proxies.

And in this case when you are using the virtual keyword on the relational properties these 'should' (in case you have not disabled it in EF) load with Lazy Loading.

Lazy Loading Loads the relational properties when you need it. Example:

```
var load = data.Orders.OrderDetails.Tolist() // Would load all OrderDetails to a list.

//Below would load all OrderDetails that has a OrderId smaller than 5
var loadSpecific = data.Orders.Where(x=> x.OrderId < 5).OrderDetails.ToList()
```

---

The case you are describing is Eager Loading('Include' statements), Nothing wrong with it. But if you are planning on using it I would consider using below syntax instead. This would give compilation error if you decide to change the name of the relational property.

```
var load = data.Orders
.Include(x => x.OrderDetails)
.Include(x => x.Categories)
```

---

I suggest you take 10-15 minutes of time and read up on it in this article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: i have lazy loading explicitly disabled.  Thanks for the suggested read, very helpful.

Comment: Remember that doing any operation on this virtual ICollection<T> will load all of them before all Where and OrderBy. I mean SQL will select all of items in collection and then manipulating them in memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EF Core this might help you:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var filteredBlogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts.Where(post => post.BlogId == 1))
        .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .ThenInclude(post => post.Tags.OrderBy(postTag => postTag.TagId).Skip(3))
        .ToList();
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include